# Explanation on uploading files to share point using vba

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I am trying to upload files to a sharepoint site, and for some reason something weird happens, where the first file with never upload, but a random amount of files after that will upload, and then sometimes an error of 'Getting list of available content types and properties' appears.

So 2 things that i need some help with, firstly how do i make it so the first file will upload, and then why am i sometimes getting the content error

here is the code i am using

```
If Dir("\\server\content\90002613\Documents\TestGB\" & saveFileName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
       MkDir ("\\server\content\90002613\Documents\TestGB\" & saveFileName)
End If

If Dir("\\server\content\90002613\Documents\TestGB\" & saveFileName & "\" & Format(lDate, "yyyy"), vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir ("\\server\content\90002613\Documents\TestGB\" & saveFileName & "\" & Format(lDate, "yyyy"))
End If

If Dir("\\server\content\90002613\Documents\TestGB\" & saveFileName & "\" & Format(lDate, "yyyy"), vbDirectory) <> "" Then
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://server/content/90002613/Documents/TestGB/" & saveFileName & "/" & Format(lDate, "yyyy") & "\GB RSM P" & Format(lDate, "mm") & "FY" & Format(lDate, "yyyy") & " " & saveFileName & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End With
End If
```

thank you

Comment: When you use the `With Activeworkbook` statement, the lines inside of it do not need to be prefixed with `Application.Activeworkbook`, they can instead be started with `.` as the `Activeworkbook` is assumed

Comment: @Mike-Hall: have a look at [Excel VBA code to upload document into SharePoint online 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133197/excel-vba-code-to-upload-document-into-sharepoint-online-2013)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save to the UNC path:

```
Const BASE_DIR As String = "\\server\content\90002613\Documents\TestGB\"
Dim dt

If Dir(BASE_DIR & saveFileName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
       MkDir (BASE_DIR & saveFileName)
End If

dt = Format(lDate, "yyyy")

If Dir(BASE_DIR & saveFileName & "\" & dt, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir (BASE_DIR & saveFileName & "\" & dt)
End If


With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs Filename:="BASE_DIR " & saveFileName & "\" & dt & _
             "\GB RSM P" & Format(lDate, "mm") & "FY" & _
             Format(lDate, "yyyy") & " " & saveFileName & ".xlsx"
    .Close False
End With
```